# Resize elements with button swipe in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, image-resizing

I have two imagelayouts, when I swipe up, bottom one is growing, above one is shrinking. When I swipe down bottom one is shrinking, above one is growing. Here is Java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    GestureDetectorCompat detector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final int minH = 350;
        final LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
        final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                if ( iv == null || iv2 == null ) {
                    return true;
                }
                distanceY*=-1;
                int height = iv.getHeight ( ) + iv2.getHeight ( );
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = iv.getLayoutParams ( );
                if ( ( int ) distanceY + layoutParams.height < minH )
                    layoutParams.height = minH;
                else if ( ( int ) distanceY + layoutParams.height > height - minH )
                    layoutParams.height = height - minH;
                else
                    layoutParams.height = ( int ) distanceY + layoutParams.height;

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = iv2.getLayoutParams ( );
                layoutParams2.height = height - layoutParams.height;

                iv.setLayoutParams ( layoutParams );
                iv2.setLayoutParams ( layoutParams2 );

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Here is XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/as" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"

            android:src="@drawable/as" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This code works well. Now what I want to do is. Place a button between these two imageviews. And when you drag the button up, above one shrinks and below one grows. When you drag the button down, below one shrinks and above one grows. How can I do that? How can I integrate the button movement into this configuration? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create the new `ImageView`, make it clickable so it can receive touch events and set the `onTouchListener` to it:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/root"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/as"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/as"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/as"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GestureDetectorCompat detector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final int minH = 350;
        final LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
        final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        final ImageView iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                if ( iv == null || iv3 == null ) {
                    return true;
                }
                distanceY*=-1;
                int height = iv.getHeight ( ) + iv3.getHeight ( );
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = iv.getLayoutParams ( );
                if ( ( int ) distanceY + layoutParams.height < minH )
                    layoutParams.height = minH;
                else if ( ( int ) distanceY + layoutParams.height > height - minH )
                    layoutParams.height = height - minH;
                else
                    layoutParams.height = ( int ) distanceY + layoutParams.height;

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = iv3.getLayoutParams ( );
                layoutParams2.height = height - layoutParams.height;

                iv.setLayoutParams ( layoutParams );
                iv3.setLayoutParams ( layoutParams2 );

                return true;
            }
        });

        iv2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return detector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want only action to happen when that 3rd button is touched. If user swipes elsewhere nothing should happen. Can it do that?

Comment: This is what the example does, but you may want to tweak the y displacement a bit

Comment: I tried it and it works well. Thanks. The only problem it sometimes shakes when I try to move finger up or down, how can I fix it? Thanks again